# Solr exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: solr.DaitchMokotoffSoundexFilterFactory

Tags: solr

I am new to solr, using version 8.8.2
I am trying to implement a datatype with phonetic matching.
I have this inside managed-schema file

```
<fieldType name="text_phonetic" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.DaitchMokotoffSoundexFilterFactory" inject="true"/>
</analyzer>
 </fieldType>
```

When I try to load the core it fails and the log contains the below exceptions:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'abetest': Unable to create core [abetest] Caused by: solr.DaitchMokotoffSoundexFilterFactory
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error loading class 'solr.DaitchMokotoffSoundexFilterFactory'
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: solr.DaitchMokotoffSoundexFilterFactory
```

In the solrconfig.xml , I tried referencing the jar files using the `<lib` tag, but I am not able to find where exactly is `solr.DiatchMokotoffSoundexFilterFactory` class located.

I am running solr from a docker container as a single node.

Comment: Which version of Solr?

Comment: I am using version 8.8.2

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround by using the class name from the jar file directly.
so, I changed the class name to be `org.apache.lucene.analysis.phonetic.DaitchMokotoffSoundexFilterFactory`
instead of
`solr.DaitchMokotoffSoundexFilterFactory`

And it worked.